# Snippet for concurrentHashMap to retrieve object or create it if absent (as atomic operation)

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrent-programming

In Java, I want to do something like this:

```
   Object r = map.get(t);
   if (r == null) {
      r = create(); // creating r is an expensive operation.
      map.put(t, r);  
   }
```

Now that snippet of code can be executed in a multithreaded environment.
`map` can be a ConcurrentHashMap.

But how do I make that logic atomic?

Please don't give me trivial solution like a 'synchronized' block.
I 'd expect this problem can be solved neatly once and for all.

Comment: There's no way to do it without synchronized. And if you're going for multithreaded you'd better get used to working with synchronized anyway.

Comment: @claesv: but there *are* ways to write it without requiring synchronization on *every* access.

Comment: @JoachimSauer ok, yeah, maybe I misread the question a bit.

Comment: @claesv I am okay with 'synchronizing' I just wonder what the best way it is ,for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is documented in concurrency in practice. 
The trick is to use a Future instead of R as object in the map.

Although I dislike this answer because it looks far far too complex.

here is the code:

```
public class Memorizer<A, V> implements Computable<A, V> {
    private final ConcurrentMap<A, Future<V>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<V>>();
    private final Computable<A, V> c;
    public Memorizer(Computable<A, V> c) { this.c = c; }

    public V compute(final A arg) throws InterruptedException {
       while (true) {
          Future<V> f = cache.get(arg);
          if (f == null) {
          Callable<V> eval = new Callable<V>() {
              public V call() throws InterruptedException {
              return c.compute(arg);
          }
       };
       FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(eval);
       f = cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);
       if (f == null) { f = ft; ft.run(); }

       try {
          return f.get();
       } catch (CancellationException e) {
          cache.remove(arg, f);
       } catch (ExecutionException e) {
          throw launderThrowable(e.getCause());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides the complication it only hide the synchronization from you (it happens in putIfAbsent) and not prevent it, also it will probably work a little slower and takes more memory

Comment: @AviramSegal: you *will* need some synchronization at some point if you need to avoid double initialization. But you can move it out of the common path and reduce its impact.

Comment: Well that is right but it doesn't save much as there is a limited number of sub maps in the concurrent hash map. but I am not sure how much it will save in practice.

Answer (score 6):

It's been solved neatly by [Guava](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/).

Use [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) and call [`build`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#build%28com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader%29) with [a `CacheLoader`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html). This will return a [`LoadingCache`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) object. If you really need a `Map` implementation, you can call [`asMap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#asMap%28%29).

There's also the older [`MapMaker`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) with its [`makeComputingMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#makeComputingMap%28com.google.common.base.Function%29), but that's deprecated in favor of the `CacheBuilder` approach.

Of course you can also implement it manually, but doing that correctly is nontrivial. Several aspects to consider are:

- you want to avoid calling `create` twice with the same input
- you want to wait for a current thread to finish creating but don't want to do that with an idle loop
- you want to avoid synchronizing in the good case (i.e. element is already in the map).
- if two `create` calls happen at the same time you want each caller to only wait for the one relevant to him.

Comment: makeComputingMap is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

try

```
    value = concurentMap.get(key);
    if(value == null) {
        map.putIfAbsent(key, new Value());
        value = map.get(key);
    }
    return value;
```

Comment: This doesn't work because two threads could enter the if statement at the same time, right?

Comment: This is working, because putIfAbsent performed atomically https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent(K, V)

Comment: I like this approach without extra dependency. `ConcurrentHashMap` is a good implementation to use.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8, method `ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent` is what you are looking for:
equivalent to the following steps for this map, but atomic:

```
 V oldValue = map.get(key);
 if (oldValue == null) {
     V newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key);
     if (newValue != null) {
         return map.putIfAbsent(key, newValue);
     } else {
         return null;
     }
 } else {
     return oldValue;
 }
```

The most common usage is to construct a new object serving as an initial mapped value or memoized result, which is what you are looking for, I think, as in:

```
 Value v = map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Value(f(k)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this maybe isn't what you're looking for, but I'll include it for sake of argument.

```
public Object ensureExistsInMap(Map map, Object t) {

    Object r = map.get(t);
    if (r != null) return r; // we know for sure it exists

    synchronized (creationLock) {
        // multiple threads might have come this far if r was null
        // outside the synchronized block
        r = map.get(t); 
        if (r != null) return r;

        r = create();
        map.put(t, r);

        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's one drawback: no two `create` calls will be executed simultanously, even for distinct keys.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is basically the [Multitone pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern#Java) with Lazy Initialization

Here is an example using double locking with modern Java locks

```
private static Map<Object, Object> instances = new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Object>();
private static Lock createLock = new ReentrantLock();

private Multitone() {}

public static Object getInstance(Object key) {
    Object instance = instances.get(key);
    if (instance == null) {
        createLock.lock();
        try {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = createInstance();
                instances.put(key, instance);
            }
        } finally {
            createLock.unlock();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. It's the Multitone pattern. But can you provide a snippet of java code to solve it ?

Comment: why does it not use the concurrent hashmap ? I am surprised maybe it's obsolete?

Comment: you are right its a problem, I fixed their example. their example can fail (get and put at the same time not allowed for HashMap)

Comment: thanks for your help, but I think it's still flawed. You are synchronizing on the ConcurrentHashMap hence assuming that is the same lock it uses internally which I don't think it's the case (or if it was, it would work by accindent)

Comment: In general you are correct but I know how the internals of ConcurrentHashMap works and it is OK.

Comment: Edited with a better solutions

Comment: Sorry I am still unconvinced. I posted my own answer which I think it works but it's damn complicated :-(.  I took it from the book concurrency in practice